# Finding formula for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What's the method for finding linear transformations formula with given it's domain subspace and range subspace?
Like say,$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\space\space, W_1 = lin((1,4,2),(2,0,7))\space,W_2 = lin((0,3,4),(7,7,8))$$
What's the formula for $\varphi(W_1) = W_2?$

There are many functions $\varphi$.
How can I determine one with Steinitz's exchange lemma?
Where can I find similar problems with solutions?
Comments on notations too are appreciated.

Comment: Do you want $\varphi(W_1) = W_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can erect $W_1$ to an ordered basis $\beta_1$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$: $$\beta_1:=\{(1,4,2)^T,(2,0,7)^T,(1,4,2)^T\times(2,0,7)^T\}$$
We can do the same for $W_2$: $$\beta_2:=\{(0,3,4)^T,(7,7,8)^T,(0,3,4)^T\times(7,7,8)^T\}$$
Let $B_1,B_2\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ whose columns originate from $\beta_1,\beta_2$ respectively. Now suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ takes the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&0\\
c&d&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $ad-bc\neq0$, and put $P=B_2AB_1^{-1}$. Then the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $T(\vec{x})=P\vec{x}$ maps $W_1$ to $W_2$. Note there are infinitely many such transformations. Unfortunately I don't know Steinitz's theorem, but I know this method works.

Comment: Note that this answer can be generalized: Any linear map $\varphi\colon V \to W$ is fixed by the image of any base under $\varphi$. Since any set of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis (true for finitely-dimensional ones, others need the axiom of choice IIRC) this means that the missing ingredient to characterize $\varphi$ from the OP is the image of some $w \in \mathbb R^3 \setminus W_1$. Since $\varphi(w)$ can be chosen arbitrarily (the proof for that is basically a generalization of your argument) we get that there are uncountably many maps satisfying the constraints.

Comment: As for Steinitz's theorem: I don't know how that one fits in here; they probably meant the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) which implies the existence of $w$ and its property in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I supposed that problem was elementary and exchange lemma could be used here. Good answer nonetheless

Comment: Thank you. Where's my upvote? lol

Comment: Yes, accepted :)